# jQuery: which is the correct way to post an ajax request with parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My code consists of a ajax request to server where there are parameters to be added to request url. Which is the correct method to implement in jQuery?

```
var param ="roomNumber="+this.roomNumber+"&roomId="+this.roomId+"&UniqueId="+this.surveyData[this.currentIndex].id+"&optionId="+optId;
```

or

json data is right way?

Answer (score 0):

In my example I use JSON data format. You can use any your server accepts

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://someUrl',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: {
        param1: '345345',
        param2: 23523
    }
}).done(function(result){
    //success
}).fail(function(e){
    //error
});
```

Comment: could you please explain about the overheads in query string and json object?

Comment: If I understood you right... you have ready `this` object with params you need to send. so you can just assign `this` object earlier to some variable, and then set it as `data` parameter value of ajax request.

Comment: for example. before $.ajax() make so: `var dataObj= this;`. In `$.ajax({...,data: dataObj,...});` Without ugly string concatenating

Comment: and url will be clean like this: `http://address.com`, not like U have `http://address.com?param1=val&param2=val&.......`